# Hydrolysis under basic conditions

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

Which route actually occurs? **Is it really true that the carboxylic acid never forms under basic conditions?**

Why not just form the -COOH and deprotonate it afterward?? Or is there a higher activation every barrier to the second route?

I understand that carboxylic *acids* don't stick around long in basic solutions but that doesn't necessarily mean they don't exist in basic solutions *at all*.

[image]

Comment: Wouldnt the mechanism depend upon the concentration of strong base taken?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I find the top mechanism unlikely for two reasons.

1) In the top mechanism, the proton removed in the first step should be way less acidic than a typical hydroxyl since the intermediate is already negatively charged. Going to a di-anion should be very far uphill, and therefore, slow. If that di-anion was ever formed, the next step would be exceedingly fast

2) In the bottom mechanism, the first step should be fast. It's intramolecular and entropically favored. The second step is instantaneous.

I can't imagine any text book includes the top mechanism. Check your book for saponification of esters.

Comment: Can I ask what book you are using?

Comment: Also if I'm not mistaken I've seen the first mechanism in Organic Chemistry by Clayden.

Comment: March's Advanced Organic Chemistry shows eight different mechanisms for ester hydrolysis under acidic and basic condtions. Some of these I would consider very unlikely, but the top mechanism that you've drawn is not included.

Comment: Neither Loudon or Maitland Jones show the top mechanism, only the bottom mechanism. Are your notes a direct copy of something your prof provided to you (on the board or otherwise)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19212/discussion-between-jerepierre-and-dissenter).

Comment: Another argument favoring @jerepierre 's position is: Why should the mechanism for basic hydrolysis of an ester be different than the mechanism for transesterification under basic conditions?  In this latter case, there is no proton to remove from the tetrahedral intermediate, so the dioxa anion cannot form.  The 2 reactions are very similar ($\ce{OH^{-} vs. OR^{-}}$), why would you invoke different mechanisms for 2 reactions so seemingly similar?

Comment: @ron would making the first mechanism described in my post "concerted" make a difference? Or does everything just boil back down to the same issue: that proton we're taking off just doesn't want to be taken off? Thinking about it, it might just make a difference. I'll open a new question.

Comment: I think it's the latter too.  Isn't there a way to ask your prof what argument he used to get the textbook folks to accept his mechanism as correct where he views your question as positive rather than confrontational?

Answer (score 1):

The reaction proceeds by a mechanism named $B_{AC_2}$ (Base-Acyl Bond-2 molecularity).

The rate is given by: (note that it is order 2 and molecularity 2) $$r=k\ce{[ester][OH- ]}$$

The $\bf rds$ is the attack of hydroxide ion. Since the last step is an acid-base reaction, it is unidirectional and reverse esterification is not possible under general conditions (I think you understand what I mean by this). Thus relative rates are also given which are well explained by this mechanism (kinda proof, considering $\bf rds$):

[image]
[image]

Comment: Acid base reactions are always unidirectional?

Comment: yes where weaker conjugate acids and weaker conjugate bases are formed.

Comment: Determining the rate law often can distinguish between mechanisms, but in this case, both proposed mechanisms could follow that rate law.

Comment: @jerepierre oh jerrie perry, This is the actual mechanism (surely), I just gave the related info to prove that this is not wrong.It's not the other way where I'm trying to prove this mechanism with the help of rate law

Comment: @ADG I agree with you that the addition/elimination followed by acid-base reaction is the mechanism that operates here. However, none of the information you have provided helps distinguish between the two mechanisms.  The relative rates would hold for either mechanism.

Comment: @jerepierre now you want me to prove an already proved and named mechanism again? maybe you are not going to accept it until i provide some source?

Comment: @ADG It wasn't my question, so it's not up to me to accept your answer. This answer repeats the mechanism that is given in the question and gives some rates that show that mechanism is reasonable. However, a full answer also has to say why it is more reasonable than the alternative. That is what the questioner wants to know. As I read it, this answer argues, "That's just the way it is" without considering the alternative mechanism. Keep in mind that I agree with you that the second mechanism is more reasonable.